# What x20 x40 x100 magnification means?

Tags: optics, terminology, microscopy

I want to buy a biologic microscope for fiber analysis, thus I need to see details of a fiber of around 20μm.

Could you please explain what "x20" magnification means? I understand that it will not convert 1mm to 20mm at a picture...

Thanks!

Comment: Magnification = image size / object size . Therefore, it will convert an object of 1mm in height into a image of 20mm height.

Comment: x20 or 20x means it will appear 20 times larger than seen by the naked eye

Comment: i've got a lot of lenses, none of them produce magnification with the factor written on it, i.e. X20 lens gives magnification about 2, X40 about 4  = they convert 1mm to 2 in the image, 1 to 4mm accordingly. thus, it is not the case i afraid

Comment: How do you know the x20 lens is giving a magnification of 2? Are the lenses and eyepieces you’re using standard for the microscope you are using?

Comment: that's easy - you put a ruler under the objective and you put another one at the ocular and compare the size of 1 mm....

Comment: I thought magnification made the object that much closer, not that much larger... Which is how you can have really cheap high magnification telescopes that really don't help a ton.

Comment: @MadHatter you are on the right track :) this is the general misconception that x10 will increase the picture 10 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others have already answered your question, I don't try to answer it again. However, from my perspective you are asking the wrong question. A microscope is not fully described by its magnification. Therefore, this is not the only quantity which you should consider. Especially in your case, it seams as if you are most interested in the spacial resolution of the microscope.  In particular, you like to resolve (transversal) structures which are smaller than 20um. Therefore, you should ask for the *transversal resolution* of the microscope and the *field of view*.

One more thing: Don't aim for the smallest transversal resolution, because this also effects the longitudinal resolution if the microscope. if your longitudinal resolution becomes small, only a small part of the field of view will be in the focus. Thus, the image becomes blurred.

Answer (score 2):

A lens with a given magnification $m$ makes the rays emanating from the object under observation reach our eyes in such a way that our eyes perceive it to be $m$ times the size of an object at the same distance i.e., a sphere of $1\ cm$ diameter appears to be a sphere of $m \ cm$ diameter at the same the same distance as original.

---

Check [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnification)

Answer (score 0):

The magnification on a microscope is similar to the magnification of lenses. A $\times20$ magnification WILL make the image height $20$ times the height of the object. Hence $1$mm will appear to be $20$mm under the microscope.

Important Note: To obtain magnification of microscope, you have to multiply objective magnification with eyepiece magnification.

Comment: take any loop and check it.